# Access Svg DOM [ContentElement - IE8]

Tags: internet-explorer, svg

I have a svg file which has a series of **path** elements inside it. Now I want to manipulate them such as change its stroke color or width.

After looking through some of the solutions from other post, here is what I am doing

```
// Here is my object tag
// <object data="/sample.svg" id="mysvg" width="675" height="675"></object>
var svg = document.getElementById('mysvg');
var svgDoc = svg.contentDocument;
//alert(svgDoc);
var graphics = svgDoc.getElementById('layer_GRAPHICS');
$(graphics).find('path').css('stroke', '#00F');
```

It works perfectly on Chrome, FF, IE 9+. But I need to make it work on IE8 also. IE 8 display my svg file ok but not the result I expected.

One thing I should point out is at **'alert line above'**, other browsers return object of type **SVGDocument** as opposed to IE8 with **HTMLDocument**.

Do you have any ideas how to make it work on IE8?

P/S: Other posts suggested I should put above code into **load** event of svg file but that is not my case. My code above will run in the click event of a button. I waited for everything to be loaded before trying to run that code.

Thank you

Comment: IE8 does not support SVG so how are you getting IE8 to display the SVG markup? Toolkits such as raphael convert the commands you issue into VML, plugins such as adobe render the SVG directly but we need to know which of these your are using.

Comment: Yes, I use Adobe SVG Viewer 3.0

Comment: You might try svg.getSVGDocument() instead of svg.contentDocument for IE8 (If you want to support non-IE8 you'll want to keep contentDocument for those environments)

Comment: Hi, I ran into runtime error **'Object does not support this property or method'** trying to call getSVGDocument(). It works fine with other browsers.

Comment: You're sure you don't have more than one element with the id mysvg on the page?

Comment: Yes, I create complete new project with only 1 Index page and test everything inside it.

Answer (score 0):

I finnaly got it to work.
Apparently you need to use **embed** tag instead of **object** to get **SVGDocument** object.

And to manipulate elements inside svg, I use the following snippet:

```
   var svg = document.getElementById('mysvg');
   var svgDoc = svg.getSVGDocument();
   var graphics = svgDoc.getElementById('layer_GRAPHICS');
   var paths = graphics.getElementsByTagName('path');
   for (var i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
       paths.item(i).style.setProperty('stroke', '#0000FF');
   }
```

In this test, I try to get all the **path** element in **layer_GRAPHICS** then change its stroke color.
You must use pure javascript in this case, jQuery does not come in handy at all. I have no idea why

Enjoy!